# How to subset SparkR data frame

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

Assume we have a dataset 'people' which contains ID and Age as a 2 times 3 matrix.

```
Id = 1 2 3
Age= 21 18 30
```

In sparkR I want to create a new dataset `people2` which contains all ID who are older than 18. In this case it's ID 1 and 3. In sparkR I would do this

```
people2 <- people$Age > 18
```

but it does not work. How would you create the new dataset?

Comment: Just for the record `people2 <- people$Age > 18` wouldn't create a new data frame even with plain old R `data.frame`. It just outputs logical vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who appreciate R's multitude of options to do any given task, you can also use the SparkR::subset() function:

```
> people <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, data.frame(Id=1:3, Age=c(21, 18, 30)))
> people2 <- subset(people, people$Age > 18, select = c(1,2))
> head(people2)
  Id Age
1  1  21
2  3  30
```

To answer the additional detail in the comment:

```
id <- 1:99
age <- 99:1
myRDF <- data.frame(id, age)
mySparkDF <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, myRDF)

newSparkDF <- subset(mySparkDF, 
        mySparkDF$id==3 | mySparkDF$id==32 | mySparkDF$id==43 | mySparkDF$id==55, 
        select = 1:2)
take(newSparkDF,5)

(1) Spark Jobs
  id age
1  3  97
2 32  68
3 43  57
4 55  45
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Say one have a dataset ID=1,2,3..,99 and age=22,...,12. If one would like to subset to the ID's 3,32,43,55 how would one do that?

Comment: @Ole - answer updated to address the extended question in your comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SparkR::filter` with either condition:

```
> people <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, data.frame(Id=1:3, Age=c(21, 18, 30)))
> filter(people, people$Age > 18) %>% head()

  Id Age
1  1  21
2  3  30
```

or SQL string:

```
> filter(people, "Age > 18") %>% head()

  Id Age
1  1  21
2  3  30
```

It is also possible to use `SparkR::sql` function with raw SQL query on a registered table:

```
> registerTempTable(people, "people"
> sql(sqlContext, "SELECT * FROM people WHERE Age > 18") %>% head()
  Id Age
1  1  21
2  3  30
```