# sparkR to filter data that is not in a data frame

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I created a 1:10000 data in R. Using SparkR, I created RDD with 1:10000 data. I want to filter so that it prints out data < 10 using SparkR. I am learning SparkR and I would appreciate any help. Please read the question carefully before marking it as a duplicate. I have also provided the code for those who likes to work with the dataframe at the end.

```
 library(SparkR)
 sc <- sparkR.init(master = "local")
 sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)
 Data <- c(1:10000)
 distData <- SparkR:::parallelize(sc,Data)
```

I want to print out all the data <10. I tried following methods to get the answer. Unfortunately, I get the respective error. The problem is not with parallelize function. I am facing a problem with filter and collect function. Please see the different trials that I ran and the associated error for details.

```
 SparkR:::filter(distData[distData < 10])

 Error: Error in SparkR:::filter(distData[distData < 10]) : 
 error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function     'filter': Error in distData[distData < 10] : 
error in evaluating the argument 'i' in selecting a method for function '[': Error in distData < 10 : 
comparison (3) is possible only for atomic and list types

SparkR:::filter(sc,distData[distData < 10])

Error in SparkR:::filter(sc, distData[distData < 10]) : 
error in evaluating the argument 'condition' in selecting a method for   function 'filter': Error in distData[distData < 10] : 
error in evaluating the argument 'i' in selecting a method for function '[':    Error in distData < 10 : 
comparison (3) is possible only for atomic and list types

SparkR:::collect(distData,filter(distData[distData<10]))

Error in filter(distData[distData < 10]) : 
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function  'filter': Error in distData[distData < 10] : 
error in evaluating the argument 'i' in selecting a method for function '[':   Error in distData < 10 : 
comparison (3) is possible only for atomic and list types


SparkR:::collect(distData, function(dist){
     print(dist[dist<10])
})

Error in if (flatten) { : argument is not interpretable as logical


filter(distData, function(dist){
  print(dist[dist<10])
})

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘filter’ for signature  ‘"RDD", "function"’
```

Following is the code that works if I work with a data frame

```
 df <- SparkR:::createDataFrame(sqlContext,distData)
 colnames(df)<-c("random")
 df1<-subset(df, nana$random<10)
 SparkR:::collect(df1)
```

Comment: I don't a lot about `sparkR`, but if you are learning why are you using the private funstions ( hidden by `:::`)? I would use the [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/R/filter.html) function , but maybe you should put your data in the long format.

Comment: It is still a duplicate. You're trying to use (as the answer to the other question explained) deprecated & deliberately hidden functionality. The answer is to use the resources in the other answer or avoid using the deprecated RDD interface.

Comment: If you read my question carefully, you will be able to understand. I am not going to justify anything here. I know that using R. The process of filtering can be done in two steps in normal R. I am using "Private function" to explore sparkR. I believe that sparkR can not handle vectors. It can only handle data if it is in a dataframe format. There are much advance users of sparkR, so correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SparkR commands only work on Spark DataFrames, and Spark DataFrames with only one column are not lists. Your filter() syntax seems to assume you are working on a list, whereas distData is a one-column DataFrame.  You must specify the column name in your filter() commands in the examples that have errors. Check your column name by running `str(distData)`.  Then apply your filter() using  `distData$colName < 10`

Examples of how to filter a Spark DataFrame using subset(), sql and filter() functions are available in the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31625982/how-to-subset-sparkr-data-frame/37635064#37635064).  @zero323 answered that question describing working syntax for the filter function.